# Сортировка строк в таблице

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, php, mysql

Какой столбец добавить в таблицу и что в него заносить, чтобы можно было потом при выводе сортировать относительно этого столбца,

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

т.е. как сделать чтоб после перетаскивания он сохранил позиции после обновления страницы

Comment: Я думаю, вам не захочется, чтобы оно _ыбло_ потом при вводе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столбец такой очень полезен. Называется ID. Чаще всего на него устанавливается `Primary Key` и `AUTO INCREMENT`.
А чтоб после перетаскивания сохранились новые позиции - это уже сложнее... Это вы в сторону Ajax копайте.